# Would "communists" be considered a proper noun?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

I know that proper nouns should be capitalized, but I'm not sure if "communists" would be considered a proper noun in this sentence:

> "They were Communists." (or "They were communists"?)

Are there cases where one or the other would be preferable? What is the rationale for this?

Comment: **They were communists** is more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I'm studying "First They Came" (a poem) and I need to know if the capitalization of "Socialists" and "Communists" is actually significant or not.

Comment: The name of a political party and its members are usually capitalized; the philosophy is usually not.  The author of the poem capitalizes Communist, Socialist, Trade Unionist.  Thus, Democratic Party, Democrat, democracy.  The socialist movement in Great Britain.  A person whose parents were members of the Communist Party is called a red-diaper baby, and his parents are/were Communists.  I disagree that one is more "appropriate" than the other.  If I were writing about the poem, I'd follow the author's capitalization.

Comment: To amplify @Xanne's point: one may be a socialist (holding the values of socialism) without being a Socialist (a member of a Socialist party.)  However, due to the peculiar history of the Communist Party/ies, I'm not sure one can be a communist without being a Communist.

Comment: But one can certainly be a Communist without being a communist (perhaps if one is living in a Communist state).

Comment: The words "Communist" and "communist" are two different things.  A Communist associates himself with the Communist party or some other such political organization which routinely uses that term for its members.  A communist, on the other hand, is someone who believes in the concept of communal property, shared income, and social equality.  Many religious orders are communist, without be at all associated with a Communist political movement.

Comment: I made an edit to try making this a question that would be useful in a broader reference sense. This may now be a duplicate, in that case. In the mean time, I think it's safe to say (linguistically, anyway) that there are "The Communists" and "The communists" and they both can mean different things. (As Hot Licks explained.)

Answer (score 3):

"Communist" is a proper noun when it refers to an organized group, the whole or part. When "communist" refers to a general philosophy, it is not a proper noun.
This will probably be a useful guide:[Writing Explained](http://writingexplained.org/ap-style/ap-style-political-parties-and-philosophies)
Example:

> Erik was a *Communist* only in name. At heart he was a *democratic* *socialist*, but the *Communist* Party was the only political organization allowed.

And

> Reg was a pariah in the *Labour Party* due to his *communist* opinions.

If dealing with political identities other than "communist", the same principles apply. The only major concern is the need to capitalize any identity derived from a proper noun.

> He is not a *communist,* he is a *Peronista.*